# Intellij project run button greyed out for a JHipster template project

Tags: intellij-idea, jhipster

I am trying to follow the video tutorial in http://www.jhipster.tech/. After I open up the project, the intelliJ only shows a compile button but not the run button. I searched around for intelliJ grey run button but it seems they are not my case. Any idea on what is going on? I am using Intellij CE version if it matters. This is my screenshot.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Probably because you did not compile with `mvnw` and so you did not generate additional code under `target` using the annotation processors. You should read our doc about [configuring your IDE](http://www.jhipster.tech/configuring-ide/) and about [using JHipster in development](http://www.jhipster.tech/development/).